# Datatables change selected row separator

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jquery datatables:

http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/select_rows.html

When you select multiple rows the id's are strung together via commas. Is there a quick easy way to modify the code so that they are strung via | (pipe) because I plan to use a text id which may contain commas and so when I explode the string I may get incorrect results.

-----------------------------UPDATE------------------------------------

Please refer to: http://www.kwedsd.byethost7.com/1.html, now if you open console in the browser, and then click on multiple rows you will see the values being strung together (the actual table rows are clickable), I would rather use | (pipe) instead of a comma, as the separator is there a way to achieve this.

The code, which strings the selected rows is:

```
$('#example tbody tr').live('click', function () {
    var aData = oTable.fnGetData( this );
    var iId = aData[0]; 
    if ( jQuery.inArray(iId, gaiSelected) == -1 ){
        gaiSelected[gaiSelected.length++] = iId;
    }else{
        gaiSelected = jQuery.grep(gaiSelected, function(value) {
            return value != iId;
        } );
    }
    console.log(gaiSelected);
    $(this).toggleClass('row_selected');
} );
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say "select multiple rows"? Maybe a code snippet would be helpful.

Comment: An example of the code you use to retrieve this comma-delimited string would be helpful.

Comment: use an ID with comma's??  why would you ever need to do that? Using `join()` on the array you can use any delimiter you want